# TNS Issue with error

Tags: oracle-12c, tnsnames

I have a Issue in Oracle I have made two database one for Demo and one for Dev  for same mount point. When I connect with Demo this can be connected but when I try to connect with DEV its not able connect. I have given to add the listner details as given below  but when I am tnsping with DEV its giving TNS 12541 error. I try to find out but not able to connect.

```
[oracle@CVM-1429 ~]$ sqlplus sys/sys as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Sat Oct 8 18:11:55 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select name from v$database;

NAME
---------
CSMEC

SQL>
```

Some more information:

```
[oracle@CVM-1429 ~]$ ps -ef|grep pmon
oracle    1286     1  0 Oct07 ?        00:00:10 ora_pmon_CSDEV
oracle   17032     1  0 Sep27 ?        00:01:40 ora_pmon_CSMEC
oracle   30817 30328  0 18:12 pts/2    00:00:00 grep pmon
[oracle@CVM-1429 ~]$
[oracle@CVM-1429 admin]$ pwd
/u03/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin
```

The content of the `listener.ora`:

```
LISTENER=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS_LIST=
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.56.184.32)(PORT=1525))
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=extproc))
    ))
SID_LIST_LISTENER=
  (SID_LIST=
    (SID_DESC=
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME=CSMEC)
      (ORACLE_HOME=/u03/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/)
      (SID_NAME=CSMEC))
   ))

LISTENER1=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS_LIST=
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.56.184.32)(PORT=1530))
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=extproc))
    ))
SID_LIST_LISTENER=
  (SID_LIST=
    (SID_DESC=
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME=CSMEC)
      (ORACLE_HOME=/u03/ORCDEV/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/)
      (SID_NAME=CSDEV))
   ))
```

The `tnsnames.ora`:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /u03/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

CSMEC =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.56.184.32)(PORT = 1525))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = CSMEC)
    )
  )

CSDEV =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.56.184.32)(PORT = 1530))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = CSDEV)
    )
  )
```

The result of the `tnsping`:

```
[oracle@CVM-1429 admin]$ tnsping CSDEV

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 08-OCT-2016 18:20:18

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.56.184.32)(PORT = 1530)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = CSDEV)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any proof of the listener running.

This does not seem to be correct:

```
LISTENER1=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS_LIST=
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.56.184.32)(PORT=1530))
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=extproc))
    ))
SID_LIST_LISTENER=
  (SID_LIST=
    (SID_DESC=
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME=CSMEC)
      (ORACLE_HOME=/u03/ORCDEV/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/)
      (SID_NAME=CSDEV))
   ))
```

If you want static registration for `LISTENER1`, then use `SID_LIST_LISTENER1`. Your tns entry contains `SERVICE_NAME=CSDEV`, and you try to register the database with `SERVICE_NAME=CSMEC` (`GLOBAL_DBNAME=CSMEC`).

Fix the above and start the listener:

```
lsnrctl start listener1
```

Then try again.

Comment: Hello Sir, I did that but i got a error -

Comment: [oracle@CVM-1429 admin]$ lsnrctl start listner1

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 10-OCT-2016 04:48:38

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u03/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

Comment: TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
System parameter file is /u03/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /u03/oracle/app/diag/tnslsnr/CVM-1429/listner1/alert/log.xml
TNS-01151: Missing listener name, listner1, in LISTENER.ORA

Listener failed to start. See the error message(s) above...

[oracle@CVM-1429 admin]$ lsnrctl

Comment: @suhail `listener1` and not `listner1`.

Comment: Why do you make life unnecessarily hard on yourself by trying to have two listeners?  Burn this into your brain: One single listener, with the default name of LISTENER and the default port of 1521 is quite capable of - indeed _was designed to_ -  service multiple databases of multiple versions running from multiple homes.  Also, you make it even more difficult to maintain by hard-coding the ip address.